# generating a graph with $N$ nodes where each node is in $m$ cliques of size $n$

Tags: algorithms

I want to randomly generate a graph with $N$ nodes where each node is in $m$ cliques of size $n$ such that every node's cliques are pairwise disjoint. This is not necessarily possible for all feasible $N$ (where feasible implies $N\geq (n-1)m$).

This problem can alternatively be formulated in the following way. Say we have the multiset $S = \{(1,m),(2,m),\ldots,(N,m)\}$ with cardinality $Nm$. Is there an algorithm that randomly assigns elements of $S$ evenly into $mN/n$ buckets such that no two buckets have more than one common element and no bucket has the same element twice.

Alternatively, can the same task be accomplished with a deterministic algorithm? A randomized algorithm would be preferred since the solution space for  given set of parameters is not necessarily a singleton.

An example for clarity is given in the lens of the latter formulation. Take $n=2,m=2,N=10$. We want to put the elements of $S = {1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10} into 10 buckets such no two buckets have more than one common element and no bucket has the same element twice. One such valid assignment to ten buckets could be:

$\{[1, 6],[1, 7],[2, 8],[2, 9],[3, 10],[3, 6],[4, 7],[4, 8],[5, 9],[5, 10]\}$.

Comment: I am assuming that there are $N$ distinguishable types, and that the $m$ copies of (for example) type-1 are indistinguishable.  Assuming so, are the buckets to be considered distinguishable or indistinguishable?

Comment: @user2661923 updated the question :).

Comment: I am not educated in this area.  So, I don't know how to attack this problem.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to distribute the objects in such a way that your two conditions are satisfied *unless* $\ n=1\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera what reasoning did you have to get to this conclusion? Did you take into account that I am allowing for $N$ to be much much larger than $n$ and $m$

Comment: @lonzaleggiera i added an example, maybe what i was asking was ambiguous, let me know if there is something i can clarify.

Comment: I don't understand the notation of your example, but I'm satisfied that a distribution is possible for those numbers, and therefore that my reasoning was wrong.  Nevertheless, I believe your two conditions must impose some limitations on what the value of $\ n\ $ can be.  If $\ N>1\ $ and $\ m>1\ $, then it's obviously not possible for $\ n=N\ $, for instance.  In that case, there are only $\ m\ $ buckets, so if every bucket contains at most one of each object, then every bucket must contain copies of both obects $\ 1\ $ and $\ 2\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera that is correct, i just don't happen to know what limitations that would be. for my example, each bucket is a list in the set.

Comment: Consider if you have 4 vertices (labeled 1, 2, 3, 4), 3 cliques, of size 3.  Buckets A,B,C,D.  An assignment could be $2,3,4 \to A$ and $1, 3,4 \to B$ and $1,2,4 \to C$ and $1,2,3 \to D$ .  That puts each vertex into a three 3-cliques by making the complete graph $K_4$.  But it also violates your rule "no two buckets have more than one common element", as $A$ and $B$ both have 3,4.

Comment: @DanielV agreed. it is not possible to do it with parameters $n=3,m=3,N=4$. I do not know which parameter sets there are solutions, although I a solution eqixsts if some condition such as $N\geq nm$ is met

Comment: @atulganju I was trying to point out that it seems the condition contradicts the first paragraph, as shown by the example.

Comment: @DanielV the first paragraph says it is not necessarily possible. why is your example a contradiction.

Comment: "I want to generate a graph with 4 nodes where each node is in 3 cliques of size 3" $K_4$ does this.  Every complete graph with v vertices does this for (v, v-1, v-1).

Comment: @DanielV i see. you are right, i’ll update the question.